# List object globally and adding local object of the class in c/c++

Tags: c++, list

```
list<Text*> textList; //global declaration of textList


void addText(int w, int h){ 
    Text *text = new Text; //error in this line
    text->init(w,h);
    textList.push_back(text);
}


void printText(){
for(list<Text*>::iterator it = textList.begin(); it != textList.end(); ++it)
        {
            (*it)->print();
        }
}
```

I've created a global `textList` of pointers of `Text` class. `addText()` & `printText()` is called from another class (c++). But getting error in creating text object

is there anyway that I can use `textList` globally and add objects to it locally in a function

Comment: what kind of error do you get? compile error, run-time error?

Comment: Does `Text` have a default constructor?

Comment: @songyuanyao yes it have a default constructor

Comment: @rashmatash runtime error

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter an error in the line `Text *text = new Text;`, then it is because **you have no matching constructor** for building a `Text` without arguments.

Because generally your code should work if you called the correct constructor.

So, **to answer your question, yes** it is possible to use `textList` like you do. The error you encounter is not related to that global variable.